# Change theme ggChoropleth

Tags: r, choropleth, ggiraph

Is it possible to change background color or theme in a `ggChoropleth` map from the `ggiraphExtra` package?

I try

```
crimes <- data.frame(state = tolower(rownames(USArrests)), USArrests)
states_map <- map_data("state")
ggChoropleth(crimes, aes(fill=Murder, map_id=state), 
             map=states_map, interactive=TRUE) + theme_bw()
```

but it returns `NULL`. I would like to remove coordenates and the background grid.

With `geom_map_interactive()` I couldn't figured it out either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `interactive=TRUE` the output of `ggChoropleth` is a `ggiraph` `htmlwidget` object and not a `ggplot` object. Hence, you cannot use `+ theme_bw()`.

I suggest to use the following solution:

```
p <- ggChoropleth(crimes, aes(fill=Murder, map_id=state), 
             map=states_map, interactive=F) 
p <- p + theme_void()
tooltip_css <- "background-color:white;font-style:italic;padding:10px;border-radius:20px 20px 20px 20px;"
ggiraph(ggobj = p, tooltip_extra_css = tooltip_css, zoom_max = 10)
```

[image]

Comment: Great! That's what I was looking for. Grazie Marco!